# No longer able to connect to a Wi-Fi network since Android Nougat

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi, android-7.0-nougat

I have an app that I use to connect to WiFi network that doesn't have connection to the Internet. It has been working fine with versions before Nougat. Since I upgraded my phone to Nougat few weeks ago, I'm not able to connect to the same WiFi network anymore. It connected briefly and disconnected and then rolled back to the previous network that has connection to the Internet. Below is the code that was working fine before Nougat.

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiConfiguration selectedConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
selectedConfig.SSID = ssid; 
selectedConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
manager.addNetwork(selectedConfig);

List<WifiConfiguration> cofigs = manager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration config : cofigs) 
{
    if(config.SSID != null && config.SSID.equals(selectedConfig.SSID)) 
    {
        manager.disconnect();
        manager.enableNetwork(config.networkId, true);
        break;
    }           
}
```

In the past, setting true in manager.enableNetwork(config.networkId, true) seemed to let the connection stay on with the network that doesn't have connection to the internet. However, since Nougat, this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the boolean parameter from the enableNetwork method is to block the other networks.
Actually, there is no way for you to tell the device to connect to certain network, the only thing that you can do is to block the other networks and that way, the only option that the device has to connect is the one that you didn't disable (the one with the id on the 1st parameter).

I would recommend you to try and check what is returned from the addNetwork and check this google issue [Google issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=192622) .

If that doesn't solve your problem, check if you are scanning somewhere else. If you scan for the available networks, your device will enable the other networks, so the others won't be disabled anymore and your device will connect to the one that it was in the beginning  or the one that has higher priority.

Hope it helped